# Prove this equation with the given determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
 a & \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{7} \\
\sqrt{3} & b & \sqrt{7} \\
\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{5} & c \\
\end{vmatrix}
=0
$$
with $a\neq\sqrt{3},\, b\neq\sqrt{5},\, c\neq\sqrt{7}.$
Show that
$$\frac{a}{a-\sqrt{3}}+\frac{b}{b-\sqrt{5}}+\frac{c}{c-\sqrt{7}}=2$$

Comment: Hi , Welcomr to MSE. please show your effort in the question body. Also to avoid downvotes and closing questions. I think this is a nice question.

Comment: Hint: try to take out the square root terms from each column of the determinant as common. Also divide the numerator and denominator of the 3 fractions in the statement that you need to prove by $\sqrt3, \sqrt5, \sqrt7$ respectively

Comment: Then replace $\frac{a}{\sqrt3}$ with some new variable $a’$ and similarly for the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in the proof statement there should be +2 on the RHS. Under that assumption:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
 a & \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{7} \\
\sqrt{3} & b & \sqrt{7} \\
\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{5} & c \\
\end{vmatrix}
=0
$$
Dividing the first, second and third columns throughout by $\sqrt3, \sqrt5, \sqrt7$ respectively:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
 a’ & 1 & 1\\
\ 1 & b’ & 1 \\
\ 1 & 1 & c’ \\
\end{vmatrix}
=0
$$
[Assuming $a’=\frac{a}{\sqrt3}$ and similarly for others.]
As shown [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-a111b111c-are-coplanar-prove-that-cfrac11acfrac11bcfrac11c1/), that implies:
$$\frac{1}{1-a’}+ \frac{1}{1-b’}+ \frac{1}{1-c’}=1$$
Substituting the original values leads to the proof of the given statement.

Comment: you are absolutely right its is +2 only the site's algorithm converted image to text maybe there the +2 got converted to -2.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that change. Also, if you consider this answer to satisfy your needs, please click the ‘accept’ (tick) icon.